# What is the difference between LaunchScreen and Splash Screen?

Tags: swift, xcode, splash-screen, launch-screen

I'm quite confused about the differences between the two and which one should be used in which occasions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42213612/activity-indicator-in-ios-launch-screen-doesnt-animate

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59700102/341994

Answer (score 1):

Generally in apple terms LaunchScreen is The First Thing To be Shown In the App while your app is not yet running. We By Ourselves create Splash Screen In Main StoryBoard(its the First Screen To be Called in AppDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions), Where we can show ActivityIndicator, animations and  any image we want to show.

AppleDeveloper website Reference :- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/specifying-your-apps-launch-screen